# Vivado timing constraints wizard

Tags: fpga, timing-analysis

I have an FPGA design that uses 2 outside clocks (INCLK and TXCLK) from an ADC to latch data also coming from an ADC (TXOUT) and a system clock.

A defined INCLK TXCLK and clk_sys as primary clocks in the timing constraints editor.

When i run the timing analysis, it appears that i have old time violation.

1) there a hold time violation for the path between the registers of U3 (LMreceiver) and U2 (capture) so i thought if added some logic between these registers i would solve the problem , but nothing changes.

2) there is a hold time violation for paths inside the modules fifo_generator_1, these modules have been generated by the IP catalog so i cannot modify them.. Is there anything i can do?

My understanding of hold time violation is that we can fix them by introducing in the path some logic to delay the signalenter image description here
[image]

[image]

Comment: If INCLK and TXCLK are the outputs of the ADC and if TXCLK is a discontinuous clock as shown in the figure, do i have to define them as primary clocks in the timing wizard constraints?

Comment: your figure is not clear. Are U3 and U2 clocked by the same clock ?